# Mongodb aggregate by several values, but limit only one of them

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have this query and it works fine, but I have to add the limit results for status 1.
As you see I bring items with status 1,2,3 but I need to limit items with status 1, I have about 100k items with status 1.

I thought I'd do the filter before the $project, but I guess it's better to limit it before the $lookup and unfortunately I have no idea how to limit it before.

```
aggregate([
{ $match: { status: {$in: [1,2,3] } },
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "participants",
        "localField": "_id",
        "foreignField": "participantId",
        "as": "participants"
    }
},
{"$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "title": 1,
    "expiresAt": 1,
    "duration:": 1,
    "cost":1,
    "seat": 1,
    "participants.username": 1
}}
```

])

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you an idea.

[sample playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u4sORnZ9O0i)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {//Group each status
      "_id": "$a",
      "data": {//Store that grouped doc
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      "elem": {//Store the status outside
        $first: "$a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {//While projecting
      "_id": "$_id",
      "data": {
        "$cond": [//have a condition
          {
            "$eq": [//If status is 1
              "$elem",
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            "$slice": [//Slice the required element
              "$data",
              1
            ]
          },
          "$data" //For other status, get every document
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```